# Intellij IDEA - Scene Builder

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm using Intellij IDEA with Scene Builder 2.0. I face some problems: Scene Builder works very slow when integrated in IDEA, and some functionality don't work at all. For example when I click on element at the form, it doesn't become selected.
When I'm using Scene Builder outside IDEA, it works well.
I'm using Fedora 21 OS. Is there a way to make Scene Builder and IDEA work fine together?

Comment: SceneBuilder integrated in Idea IntelliJ is slower when compared to its standalone counterpart. I would advice you to always open the fxml's in standalone SceneBuilder by right-clicking on them and select `Open In SceneBuilder`

Comment: I always do it that way, yes, but it would be much more comfortable to use Scene Builder inside IDE